# Newly created apple developer account not showing app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have been building my first ios app, and have just purchased an enrollment on the apple developer programme.

The bundle identifier is set as I want (i'm pretty sure it is unique)
The signing options in xcode is as follows:

Automatically manage signing is **checked**,

Team is set as: **[My Name] (Personal Team)**

provisioning profile is **xcode managed profile**

and signing certificate is: **IPhone Developer [myemail] (someid)**

When i log into the developer portal

I tried to add the appId by certificates>identifier>app id> the setting bundle identifier there. but it came as An App ID with Identifier is not available.

I feel as though it has created 2 separate accounts or something? like a team one and a single one - in

- why cant i see my app in the developer portal, and more importantly how can i get to see it with in the developer portal.

Note: In the membership section of the dev portal my role is set as Agent

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that **Xcode->Preferences->Accounts** is Logged in with the correct **Apple ID** that you have signed up with.

Once you are logged in, click the account that you logged in with, and "**View Details**..." , there you can **Download All Profiles** , and finally **Done**.

EDIT:
Check this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/AddingYourAccounttoXcode/AddingYourAccounttoXcode.html) for guidelines how to add step by step:

Comment: My name is listed twice here one with role Agent, and one with role user

Comment: @raklos Have you selected your Agent and "View Details , and "Download All Profiles", and in Xcode , you should set the "TEAM" in Xcode project to your Agent, not personal team.

Comment: when i click on the " i " next to Xcode Manged Profile its pos up with IOS Team provisioning profile:my bundle id, then exires in 2 days in red

Comment: @raklos Check the documentation in my updated answer. There is a simple step-by-step with screenshots how to configure Xcode correctly.